# How to construct a planar graph (or a class of planar graphs) with minimum degree 5 of diameter 2?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

A subset $D$ of the vertices of a graph G is called a dominating set if every vertex of
$G - D$ is adjacent to a vertex of $D$, and the domination number of $G$, denoted $\gamma(G)$, is
the minimum cardinality of a dominating set.

The following article proves that any planar graph with diameter 2 has domination number at most 3.

- MacGillivray G, Seyffarth K. Domination numbers of planar graphs[J]. Journal of Graph Theory, 1996, 22(3): 213-229.

As part of the proof, the authors also showed that planar
graphs with minimum degree 5 of diameter two have domination number at most three. But the author did not construct the corresponding example graph.

My question is

- whether a planar graph with  minimum degree of 5 having diameter 2 exists. (Of course, it is better to construct a class of there graphs)

Another question is

- whether a planar graph with  minimum degree of 5 of diameter 2 having domination number three exists.
  (Of course, it is better to construct a class of there graphs)

I am aware that there are some planar graphs with minimum degree 5 of diameter 3 (see an icosahedron graph as a example).

[image]

Or we can see that some planar graphs with minimum degree 4 of diameter 2 (see an octahedral graph as a example).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the first question:

There is no planar graph of diameter two with minimal degree $5$.
This follows from [Seyffarth theorem](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/jgt.3190130512),
which is formulated as follows.

Let $G$ be a maximal planar graph with maximum degree $\Delta$
and diameter two. Then the minimum degree $\delta<5$ (Theorem 2), p.623.